# invalid escape in pattern HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, input

I am trying to make an `<input>` field that uses a pattern to check if the input is a valid windows file path.

The pattern I have is

```
/^(?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[a-zA-Z_\-\s0-9\.()~!@#$%^&=+';,{}\[\]]+)+\.(exe)$/g
```

However, when putting this into the pattern attribute of an `<input>` field:

```
<input id="path" type="text" pattern="^(?:[\w]\:|\)(\[a-zA-Z_\-\s0-9\.()~!@#$%^&=+';,{}[]]+)+\.(exe)$">
```

An error is displayed in the console saying:

```
Pattern attribute value
^(?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[a-zA-Z_\-\s0-9\.()~!@#$%^&=+';,{}\[\]]+)+\.(exe)$ is
not a valid regular expression:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular
expression: /^(?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[a-zA-Z_\-\s0-9\.()~!@#$%^&=+';,{}\[\]]+)+\.(exe)$/:
Invalid escape
```

I have tried several ways of writing this pattern, but none seem to work.

Comment: How is that pattern "put" into the pattern attribute? Is it through JavaScript or is it directly in the HTML?

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: ` <input id="path" type="text" pattern="^(?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[a-zA-Z_\-\s0-9\.()~!@#$%^&=+';,{}\[\]]+)+\.(exe)$">    ` : Like so (it appears that the surrounding slashes are inserted so i have omitted them)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol for example C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe It works in online regex testers just not in practice.

Comment: The `pattern` attribute already matches the whole string, so `^` and `$` are not needed. It's worth also noting that file paths can use `/` instead of \.

Comment: It still doesn't work without the `^ and $`

Comment: Try `pattern="(?:\w:|\\)(\\[\w\s.()~!@#$%^&=+';,{}[\]-]+)+\.exe"`. The `^` and `$` abchors are not necessary as this pattern is anchored by default.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks that worked, can you put it as an answer so i can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You only need to escape the characters in the character class that must be escaped otherwise, you will always get this error.

**2023 Update**:

Now, that `pattern` attribute is compiled with the `v` flag, escaping rules have become way stricter. See [Valid with the RegExp u flag, but not with the v flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76287241/3832970) for more details.

The current solution will look like

```html
pattern="(?:\w:|\\)(\\[\w\s.\(\)~!@#$%^&=+';,\{\}\[\]\-]+)+\.exe"
```

Note the `[`, `{`, `}`, `(` and `)` that are escaped now.

**Original answer**

Use

```
pattern="(?:\w:|\\)(\\[\w\s.()~!@#$%^&=+';,{}[\]-]+)+\.exe"
```

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8jk7gkr/1/)

**Details**:

- The hyphen must be at the end of the character class
- The `]`  inside the character class must be escaped
- The `[` and `.` must not be escaped
- The `:` must never be esacaped, it is never a special character
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` = `\w`
- The `pattern` is always anchored by default, you need no `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: Invalid regular expression: /[\w'\,\.\(\)\-\\/\+\!]{1,}/: Invalid escape, I am getting this error for one of my form:input tags regex in pattern attribute, in JSP page. Any suggestions on this escaping of backslash  \ ?

Comment: @rinilnath Of course. Why did you escape every char in the character class? *You only need to escape the characters in the character class that must be escaped*. So, something like `pattern="[\w\x27,.()/+!-]+"` will work.

Comment: so i can escape that \  without this?, i tried this in https://www.regextester.com/ it was escaping \, any easier way please

Comment: Stribizew, Thanks much, but one small doubt, is it ok to escape the "SPACE" character with backslash or i can just give the space somewhere in regex group

Comment: @rinilnath **You only need to escape the characters in the character class that must be escaped.** Is space a special regex metacharacter? No. So, DON'T.

Comment: Lately, I discovered that [*JavaScript* introduced the **v** flag](https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag). It seems to be also enabled on the *pattern* HTML attribute because I was having a character class containing a hyphen, which I put at the end `[a-z-]`, but it didn't work on Chrome, perhaps because I was using `\p{L}`, probably triggering the **v** flag. **You now need to escape it**: `[a-z\-]`. I thought this might be useful as things have changed quite a lot since your answer in 2016! Typically, it's now possible to do difference/subtraction or intersection on character classes.

Comment: @PatrickJanser Yes, see [Valid with the RegExp u flag, but not with the v flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76287241/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: but how do we set the flag? as the pattern is automatically enclosed by `^(?:` and `)$` and doesn't have pattern delimiters, will the flags be automatically enabled (for example the **u** or **v** flags)? Or should one add them in the pattern? I know that *PCRE* handles inline flags such as `(?i:help)` but *JavaScript* doesn't seem to :-/

Comment: @PatrickJanser You can't set flags in `pattern` attribute. They are "hard-coded".