# Valid Regex causes "Unable to check" if used as HTML input's pattern

Tags: javascript, html

> Unable to check <input pattern='/^[a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9äöüÄÖÜß@\s+-_.,{}[]()#']+$/'> because the pattern is not a valid regexp: invalid identity escape in regular expression

```html
First Try: <br />
<input type="text" pattern="/^[a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9äöüÄÖÜß@\s\+\-\_\.\,\{\}\[\]\(\)\#\']+$/">
<br />
Second Try: <br />
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9äöüÄÖÜß@\s\+\-\_\.\,\{\}\[\]\(\)\#\']+">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [invalid escape in pattern HTML/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409872/invalid-escape-in-pattern-html-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [MDN on the `pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern#overview):

> ... **No forward slashes** should be specified around the pattern text.

The forward slashes are JavaScript syntax for regular expression literals.

Quoting from the same page:

> ... **the 'u' flag is specified** when compiling the regular expression, so that the pattern is **treated as a sequence of Unicode code points**, instead of as ASCII.

And quoting [MDN's Guide *Regular expressions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#using_unicode_regular_expressions):

> - **Unicode regular expressions do not support so-called "identity escapes"**;
>   that is, patterns where an escaping backslash is not needed and
>   effectively ignored. ...

This means only required character escapes are valid.

You should also be aware that ... (quoting from the same page)

> - **The `-` character is interpreted differently within character classes**. In particular, for Unicode regular expressions, `-` is interpreted as a literal `-` (and not as part of a range) only if it appears at the start or end of the character class.

In conclusion, your first pattern in fixed could look like this:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9äöüÄÖÜß@\s+\-_\.,\{\}\[\]\(\)#']+$">
```